# Windows 7, Taskbar is HUGE

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar

just got myself a second LCD for Christmas and ever since I plugged it in I have a problem with my taskbar. I have the taskbar at the right side of the screen and now it's abnormally huge.

Here's a screenshot of the situation:

[image]

Anyone have an idea? I searched around but couldn't find anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply right click on any empty space on the taskbar and untick "Lock the taskbar"

[image]

Then, when you hover your mouse over the edge of the taskbar, it should change and let you shrink the taskbar to a more "normal" size.

That being said, before Windows 7 made the taskbar really good and into a feature, I used to (in XP at least) have the taskbar larger than that and in the middle of both screens and used the auto hide option.

Answer (score 8):

[image]